# Linq to SQL Concat / Union does not working on the Custom Class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Linq to SQL Concat / Union does not working on the Custom Class.

**Custom Class**

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Accesses> Accesses { get; set; }
}
```

**Union:**

```
IQueryable<CustomClass> objQuery = context.Users       
    .Where(W => W.Auth == true)
    .Select(S => new CustomClass()
    {
        FirstName = S.FirstName,
        LastName = S.LastName,
        Accesses = context.AuthFalse
                    .Where(W => W.UID = S.ID)
                    .Select(S1 => new Accesses()
                    {
                        AccessesID = S1.AccessesID,                                                
                    })
                    .ToList(),
    })
    .Union(context.Users    
        .Where(W => W.Auth == true)                            
        .Select(S => new CustomClass()
        {
            FirstName = S.FirstName,
            LastName = S.LastName,
            Accesses = context.AuthTrue
                        .Where(W => W.UID = S.ID)
                        .Select(S1 => new Accesses()
                        {
                            AccessesID = S1.AccessesID,                                                
                        })
                        .ToList(),
        })
    );
```

When I executing the above query I got the following error:

> The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection
>   ResultType of the specified argument.\r\nParameter name: argument

**Concat**

```
IQueryable<CustomClass> objQuery = context.Users       
    .Where(W => W.Auth == true)
    .Select(S => new CustomClass()
    {
        FirstName = S.FirstName,
        LastName = S.LastName,
        Accesses = context.AuthFalse
                    .Where(W => W.UID = S.ID)
                    .Select(S1 => new Accesses()
                    {
                        AccessesID = S1.AccessesID,                                                
                    })
                    .ToList(),
    })
    .Concat(context.Users    
        .Where(W => W.Auth == true)                            
        .Select(S => new CustomClass()
        {
            FirstName = S.FirstName,
            LastName = S.LastName,
            Accesses = context.AuthTrue
                        .Where(W => W.UID = S.ID)
                        .Select(S1 => new Accesses()
                        {
                            AccessesID = S1.AccessesID,                                                
                        })
                        .ToList(),
        })
    );
```

When I executing the above query I got the following error:

> {"The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll'
>   Operation2='MultiStreamNest'"}

Finally, What I want to do is that if the **Auth** field of the Users table is **true** than I want the data from the **AuthTrue** table and want to store in the **List** field, If the **Auth** field of the Users table is **false** than I want the data from the **AuthFalse** table and want to store in the **List** field.

I want all this to do in the single query or maximum 2 to 3 query.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you should rewrite yours Concat attempt like this: start with users then do 2 left joins to AuthFalse and AuthTrue add filtering by user.Auth field and proper right match, do select to anonymous class with user.Id, user.LastName, user.FirstName + either AuthFalse match or AuthTrue  match. At this stage queriable must by casted ToEnumerable then all is left is proper grouping + selection.

Comment: @VitaliyKalinin, Thanks, Can you please provide some code snippet? Because I does not understand What you want to saying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite yours Concat attempt like this:
1. Start with users 
2. Then do 2 left joins to AuthFalse and AuthTrue 
3. Add filtering by user.Auth field and proper right match
4. Do select to anonymous class with user.Id, user.LastName, user.FirstName + either AuthFalse match or AuthTrue match. At this stage queriable must by casted ToEnumerable 
5. Then all is left is proper grouping + selection.

Here is this steps as complete unit test:

```
public class CustomClass
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<CustomAccesses> Accesses { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomAccesses
    {
        public int Rights { get; set; }
    }


    public class Accesses
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public Guid UID { get; set; }
        public int Rights { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool Auth { get; set; }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class QueryTests
    {
        private static readonly User TrueUser = new User
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FirstName = "TrueFirstName",
            LastName = "TrueLastName",
            Auth = true
        };

        private static readonly User FalseUser = new User
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FirstName = "FalseFirstName",
            LastName = "FalseLastName",
            Auth = false
        };

        private static readonly User[] DbUsersMock =
        {
            TrueUser,
            FalseUser
        };

        private static readonly Accesses[] DbAuthTrueMock =
        {
            new Accesses
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UID = TrueUser.ID,
                Rights = 1
            },
            new Accesses
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UID = TrueUser.ID,
                Rights = 2
            }
        };

        private static readonly Accesses[] DbAuthFalseMock =
        {
            new Accesses
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UID = FalseUser.ID,
                Rights = -1
            },
            new Accesses
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UID = FalseUser.ID,
                Rights = -2
            }
        };

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var users = DbUsersMock.AsQueryable();

            var authTrue = DbAuthTrueMock.AsQueryable();

            var authFalse = DbAuthFalseMock.AsQueryable();


            var result = users
                .GroupJoin(
                    authTrue,
                    u => u.ID,
                    ta => ta.UID,
                    (user, accesses) => new
                    {
                        user,
                        accesses = accesses.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    }
                )
                .SelectMany(
                    ua => ua
                        .accesses
                        .Select(
                            trueAccess => new
                            {
                                ua.user,
                                trueAccess
                            }
                        )
                )
                .GroupJoin(
                    authFalse,
                    ua => ua.user.ID,
                    fa => fa.UID,
                    (userAccess, accesses) => new
                    {
                        userAccess,
                        accesses = accesses.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    }
                )
                .SelectMany(
                    uaa => uaa
                        .accesses
                        .Select(
                            falseAccess => new
                            {
                                uaa.userAccess.user,
                                uaa.userAccess.trueAccess,
                                falseAccess
                            }
                        )
                )
                .Where(
                    uaa => uaa.user.Auth
                        ? uaa.trueAccess != null
                        : uaa.falseAccess != null
                )
                .Select(
                    uaa => new
                    {
                        uaa.user.ID,
                        uaa.user.FirstName,
                        uaa.user.LastName,
                        AccessID = uaa.user.Auth
                            ? uaa.trueAccess.ID
                            : uaa.falseAccess.ID,
                        Rights = uaa.user.Auth
                            ? uaa.trueAccess.Rights
                            : uaa.falseAccess.Rights
                    }
                )
                .OrderBy(uaa => uaa.ID)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(uaa => uaa.ID)
                .Select(
                    g => new CustomClass
                    {
                        FirstName = g.First().FirstName,
                        LastName = g.First().LastName,
                        Accesses = g
                            .GroupBy(uaa => uaa.AccessID)
                            .Select(
                                uaa => new CustomAccesses
                                {
                                    Rights = uaa.First().Rights
                                }
                            )
                            .ToList()
                    }
                )
                .ToArray();

            Assert.That(result.Length, Is.EqualTo(DbUsersMock.Length));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, You used the `AsEnumerable()` method which will fired the query, But I don't want to fired the query, Because after that I have to add the search keyword conditions and sorting like facility on it. All of it I want to do it on the database not in the memory.

Comment: I have placed AsEnumerable() exactly at place where LinqToSql is able to deal properly with yours requirements. If yours description is incomplete then you should be ready to incomplete solution.

Comment: Actually this code is snippet for explanation which I have posted as comment. I'll copy paste my comment in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways. A simple way to do this is:
Take two lists, one for when it is TRUE and another for when it is FALSE. Then in the resulting list use the ADDRANGE method.
This method (ADDRANGE) will only work when you are working with lists.

Example:

```
var listTrue = ctx.Users.Where(...).Select(s=> new CustomClass{...}).ToList();
var listFalse = ctx.Users.Where(...).Select(s=> new CustomClass{...}).ToList();
var result = new List<CustomClass>();
result.AddRange(listTrue);
result.AddRange(listFalse);
return result;
```